# How do I use GraphDiff when DBContext is abstracted?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have just learned about GraphDiff, and how it is supposed to take care of all the differences between the disconnected entity and the one stored in the database.

The thing is that I do not know how to use GraphDiff, I tried the [documentation](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/.), but I didn't understand it well.

I am using an abstracted DBContext, through an Interface and using DbSet so I could perform Unit Testing on them:

```
public interface IDbRepositories
{
    IDbSet<Client> ClientsDB { get;}
    AppIdentityDbContext DB { get; }
    IDbSet<Contacts> ContactsDB { get; }
    IDbSet<ExposureResult> ExposureDB { get; }
    IDbSet<OrderMods> OrderModsDB { get; }
    IDbSet<ProductDetails> ProductDetailsDB { get; }

    IDbSet<OrderProcess> OrderProcessDB { get; }

    IDbSet<Order> OrderDB { get; }

    void SaveChanges();
}
```

This is the actual class implementing the interface:

```
public class DbRepositories : IDbRepositories
{
    private AppIdentityDbContext db = new AppIdentityDbContext();

    //Get DB Context. This is done this way, so a Mock can be injected when testing
    public IDbSet<Client> ClientsDB
    {
        get { return db.Clients; }
    }

    public AppIdentityDbContext DB
    {
        get { return db; }
    }

    public IDbSet<Contacts> ContactsDB
    {
        get { return db.Contacts; }
    }

    public IDbSet<ExposureResult> ExposureDB
    {
        get { return db.ExposureTBL; }
    }

    public IDbSet<OrderMods> OrderModsDB
    {
        get { return db.OrderMods; }
    }

    public IDbSet<ProductDetails> ProductDetailsDB
    {
        get { return db.ProductDetailsTBL; }
    }

    public IDbSet<OrderProcess> OrderProcessDB
    {
        get { return db.OrderProcesses; }
    }

    public IDbSet<Order> OrderDB
    {
        get { return db.OrderTBL; }
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        this.db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

---

Now, the problem part is in here:

```
public bool SaveOrderChanges(OrderProcess[] Order, int OrderID, int uid)
{
    //2nd Step:
    var ComparableObject = dbs.OrderProcessDB.Where(x => x.OrderID == OrderID).ToList();
    var Objections = dbs.OrderDB.Where(x => x.OrderID == OrderID).FirstOrDefault();
    dbs.DB.UpdateGraph(dbs.OrderDB, m => m.OwnedCollection());
    dbs.SaveChanges();
    return true;
 }
```

I'd like to tell the differences between the Order parameter and the one I extract from OrderProcessDB. These are a One to Many Relationship.

I do not know how to use GraphDiff for this scenario. Any ideas?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to use GraphDiff... Does someone know how to use it? I do not understand it how to use it from the official page. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just expose the base DbContext object in the interface, but that would violate basic principles of encapsulation. The challenge is that the `UpdateGraph` method is a static extension off of the concrete `DbContext` class. Here is my solution:

First the interface:

```
public interface IMyDbContext
{
    ...

    TEntity UpdateGraph<TEntity>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<TEntity>, object>> mapping = null) where TEntity : class, new();
}
```

Then the actual DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    ...

    public TEntity UpdateGraph<TEntity>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<TEntity>, object>> mapping = null) where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        return ((DbContext)this).UpdateGraph(entity, mapping);
    }
}
```

And lastly example usage inside of a repository:

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly IMyDbContext _myDbContext;

    public MyRepository (IMyDbContext myDbContext)
    {
        _myDbContext = myDbContext;
    }

    public async Task<SomeEntity> UpdateSomeEntity(SomeEntity updatedSomeEntity)
    {
        _myDbContext.UpdateGraph(updatedSomeEntity, map => map.OwnedCollection(p => p.SomeChildCollection));
        await _myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return updatedSomeEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Woot! Thanks for the input. It's been almost 3 years since that! I think I ended up implementing a different solution altogether. Edit: Now I remember, I would manually go over the entity and set the state as "modified" because I think the solution didn't work at first.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I just found out about GraphDiff and can hopefully help anyone else looking.

This is how you use GraphDiff:

```
 db.UpdateGraph(orderToUpdate, map => map
                    .AssociatedCollection(t => t.Products)
                    .OwnedCollection(t => t.PaymentMethods));
```

This says to update the Order object, and that the Order owns the PaymentMethods (meaning it can actually remove those entities), and is associated with the Products entities (meaning it will remove them from the reference table).

Comment: Thanks a million for the help! Hopefully will serve for many people to come :D